# python too many values to unpack xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, valueerror

I am having a difficult time finding out what the issue could be here. I understand the error and am following the tutorial here, https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html, for writing to an excel workbook but I still keep getting the error `for first, last in accounts:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` If anyone could assist then that would be great. I have tried removing the methods for first and last name as well in the accounts tuple for create_accounts() method and replacing with string's but that hasn't helped either.

```
import xlsxwriter
from account import Acc


class FillExcel(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.obj = Acc()

def create_accounts(self):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('accounts05.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    accounts = ([self.obj.first_name(), self.obj.last_name()])

    # Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
    row = 0
    col = 0
    print(accounts)
    for first, last in accounts:
        worksheet.write(row, col, first)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, last)
        row += 1

    workbook.close()

test = FillExcel()
test.create_accounts()
```

Here is the class that contains my methods first_name and last_name for the account object.

```
import random
import string

# create an account array object that will be used
# in xlsxwriter literal

name=["Beck","Glenn","Becker","Carl","Beckett","Samuel","Beddoes","Mick","Beecher"]


class Acc(object):

    def first_name(self):
        f_name = random.choice(name)
        return f_name

    def last_name(self):
        l_name = random.choice(name)
        return l_name

    def addy_line1(self, address):
        chars1 = string.ascii_uppercase
        chars2 = ''.join(random.choice(chars1) for i in range(4))
        return chars2 + address

    def phone_number(self, area_code):
        rand_num = random.sample(range(10), 7)
        number = str((''.join(map(str, rand_num))))
        return area_code + number


if __name__ == "__main__":
    accObj = Acc()
    accObj.first_name()
    accObj.last_name()
    accObj.addy_line1('123 West St.')
    accObj.phone_number('212')
```

Here is the full exception that I am getting. (edited)

```
['Blanchet', 'Ingmar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Carsten/PycharmProjects/Dna_Nike/Obj_Creator.py", line 29, in <module>
test.create_accounts()
  File "C:/Users/Carsten/PycharmProjects/Dna_Nike/Obj_Creator.py", line 21, in create_accounts
    for first, last in accounts:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Please post the full exception, not just the description, so we can verify that it really is coming from `for first, last in accounts:`. But assuming it is that line, you have a `print(accounts)` right before it. What does it print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
accounts = ([self.obj.first_name(), self.obj.last_name()])
```

At first glance, this looks like a tuple of lists, and the only list in the tuple has two values. So, `for first, last in accounts:` ought to work, right?

But it's not actually a tuple.

Commas create tuples in Python; parentheses are just for disambiguation. The value `(2+3)` is not a tuple of the single element `5`, it's just the number `5`. You need `2+3,` (or `(2+3,)`) if you want a tuple with that one element.

And that's exactly what's happening in your code. Without the comma, you're just creating the list `[self.obj.first_name(), self.obj.last_name()]`. When you iterate over that, you don't get a 2-element list, you get a name (presumably a string), so you're effectively doing `first, last = first_name`, which is nonsense.<sup>1</sup>

To fix it, just add the comma:

```
accounts = ([self.obj.first_name(), self.obj.last_name()],)
```

Or you could just use a list. You're not really looking for immutability here (otherwise you'd have a tuple of tuples, not a tuple of lists), or for a fixed-size collection where position is meaningful, or for a micro-optimization (a tuple should shave ~6% of the <100 bytes…), and those are the main reasons to use tuples in place of lists:

```
accounts = [[self.obj.first_name(), self.obj.last_name()]]
```

---

<sub>1. Actually, it's a perfectly legal statement, because strings are iterable—they iterate their individual characters. But a first name like, say, `'Balla'` has 5 characters, and you're trying to unpack those 5 elements into 2 variables. Hence the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.</sub>

Comment: thank you so much. that was indeed the issue. I actually thought to add the comma in too and after I looked, I now see that I put the comma inside the square brackets of the list and not outside the list, thus making me think this was not the issue. bonehead mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @BallaBaby In Python, lists, unlike tuples, _are_ made by the brackets, so `[2+3]` is a 1-element list. Because you're usually dealing with things like `(1, 2, 3)` vs. `[1, 2, 3]`, you don't notice the difference until the first time you run into this bug, which everyone does at some point…

Comment: one other question. How would you suggest I go about creating more of these list elements and putting them in a tuple? I can't loop through a tuple and append since tuples are immutable. Is there any way to take a list of lists and turn that into a tuple of lists? I'm sorry if the question is vague. Just thought I'd ask

Comment: @BallaBaby Right, you can't `append` to a tuple. You can write `accounts = accounts + (account,)`, but this creates a whole new copy for each "append", which can be a bad idea if the thing is going to get large. (It takes quadratic rather than amortized-linear time, if that means anything to you.) So, creating a list, and then converting to a tuple at the end (with `accounts = tuple(accounts)`), as you suggest, is usually the best answer. (Unless… do you know how to write generators? Create a generator that produces the accounts lazily, then do `accounts = tuple(lazy_accounts)`.)

Comment: @BallaBaby But meanwhile, is there a reason this needs to be a tuple rather than a list? This really does seem like a paradigm use case for a list.

Comment: thanks for the response. My assumption is that writing to an excel workbook needs data in form of a tuple (though I could be wrong). I was just following along with the docs. I do plan on having the data get large and I realize it probably wouldn't be best to constantly be creating new tuples. I do not know how to do generators but it is on my bucket list of things to learn so no better time like the present I guess. I will start there. Thank you.